# How to add "Loading icon" and dim the background when something is process in backend?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm newbie to asp.net, javascript.

I have multiple views in a page in my ASP.NET application which is implemented using MVC5 Razor engine. Each view looks like a panel and they are cshtml files. Not aspx. Each panel has submit buttons individually where they are connected to its own API via Ajax.BeginForm option.

I want to know how can I add a Processing/Loading icon in the center of the screen and dim the background until submit has finished and returned back to my view ??

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("FilterReport", "Report", new AppAjaxOptions()
{
    ExtendOnSuccess = "ReportView.onFilteringCompleted(data)",
    UpdateTargetId = "filterContent",
}))
{

//some <div> .... </div> here

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@LanguagesFacade.GetValue(DictionaryKey.Filter)</button>
}
```

Signature of the API looks like this:

```
public PartialViewResult FilterReport(ReportFilterViewModel reportFilterViewModel)
```

Please let me know how to implement a loading icon on screen during the execution of this API simultaneously ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `AjaxOptions` class has `OnBegin` and `OnSuccess` properties that can call javascript functions to update your view

Comment: This needs javascript / jquery with HTML and CSS.. nothing to do with mvc.

Comment: @Reddy, It has everything to do with MVC. OP wants to do it in `Ajax.BeginForm()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I meant like the solution for showing the loading icon is pure HTML, CSS, Javascript..

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thanks for your suggestion. I used OnBegin to load my loading symbol. I want to hide the same when it is done with its work. But OnSuccess is resulting in an exception.
It looks like this:
Cybercom.DFAII.Office.Infrastructure.ApplicationInvalidOperationException: This property is set in Office.Mvc.AppAjaxOptions. Do not override it.

Not able to find the place to hide it. Any pointers on this ?

Comment: What is `AppAjaxOptions`? That's not part of MVC. Are you using some additional plugin?

Comment: Yes. Its internally implemented plugin. Now i see OnSuccess has been overridden and that is already used as one of the options. Hence I am not able to have another OnSuccess. The overridden one had different name totally, so i couldnt make out. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample snippet. This should help you

```js
//for demo
$('button').on('click', function() {
  showLoadingIcon();  //call this when you want to show loading icon
});

//----------------------------Core functionality----------------------------------//
function showLoadingIcon() {
  var loadingImage = '<div class="loading-div">' +
    '<span class="loading-icon " style="opacity:none;">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x fa-spin" style="margin-left: 47px;"></i>' +
    '</span></div>';

  $('body').append(loadingImage);
}

function hideLoadingIcon() {       //call this when you want to hide loading icon
 $('#loading_icon_div').remove();
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.loading-div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.loading-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0px 0px -50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>show loading icon..</button>
  some random text goes here..
</div>
```